# Remote VNC or RDP session is different from the one being shown on monitor hooked on RPi

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc, raspberry-pi

Bringing this from stack overflow.

I just bought a Raspberry Pi and hooked it up on my TV via HDMI.

Later, I installed tightvncserver on it, and I also followed this guide (https://www.modmypi.com/blog/remotely-accessing-the-raspberry-pi-via-rdp-gui-mode) to install RDP on it.

On both cases, the same thing happened:

When I access my raspberry pi via VNC or RDP, it starts a new session. I want to be able to control from my PC what appears on my TV hooked up on Pi.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct since a new display is created and shown.

To connect to the currently running display you need to use something like [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) or Vino which permit you to export the :0 display. You can try to check this [link](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=38922) for complete experience specifically for Raspberry PI.